# Image not uploading through forms on registration

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with my forms, I've been trying to upload an image when a user registers but it does not submit because an error message is sent which says "This field is required". I'm not too sure where the issue is but I have tried to do this "a_form=InformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)". But I still got the error message("This field is required") upon registration of the user, even though I have selected the image to be uploaded with the user when registering. I would like to know if a solution could be proffered. The image and code snippet show the issue too. Thanks
[image]
**FORMS**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Information

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm'}))
    

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class InformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #sex=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    department = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Department'}))
    majors = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Majors'}))
    nationality = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nationality'}))
    date_of_birth = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'yyyy/mm/dd'}))
    passport_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Passport number'}))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone number'}))
    student_passport = forms.ImageField()
    

    class Meta:
        model=Information
        fields=['department','majors','degree','years','nationality','date_of_birth','passport_number','phone_number','sex','student_passport']



class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']

class InformationUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Information
        fields=['phone_number']
```

**VIEWS**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm,UserUpdateForm ,InformationUpdateForm,InformationForm

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'student/home.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        a_form=InformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and a_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            information = a_form.save(commit=False)
            information.user = user
            information.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        a_form = InformationForm()
    context={'form':form,'a_form':a_form }#,'a_form':a_form
    return render(request, 'student/register.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'student/profile.html')

@login_required
def passport(request):
    return render(request,'student/passport.html')

@login_required
def profile_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form=UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        i_form=InformationUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.information)
        if u_form.is_valid() and i_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            i_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form=UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        i_form=InformationUpdateForm(instance=request.user.information)
    context={'u_form': u_form,
            'i_form':i_form}
    return render(request, 'student/profile_update.html',context)
```

**REGISTER.HTML**

```
{% extends "student/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                {{ a_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
             <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `form` tag in your template?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, I have. but the error message still pops up. Let me edit the question and show you with the html template too.

Comment: @DanielIhenacho put enctype into your form tag

Comment: @zero Thanks alot. I'm grateful. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is not supposed  to be on the `<fieldset>`  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{form}} //your form stuff
</form>
```

you applied `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to `<fieldset>` please add in `<form>` tag

Comment: update my answer you applied this in formset instead of form

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm grateful. As you said `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is supposed to be on the `<form>` tag on not on the `<fieldset>` .